# Transaction vs Truncation Database Cleaner

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, transactions, cucumber, rubygems

Recently I had a problem with one of my cucumber scenarios. Certain entries in my test database were disappearing whilst the feature was running. I solved the problem by changing the line

```
DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
```

to

```
DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
```

I'm not sure why that helped. There is a table on the database cleaners gem webpage, but it dosen't really say what the two terms mean. Any help on understanding the difference between the two concepts would be great.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Putting it in a very simple way: truncation removes all data from the database and transaction rollbacks all changes that has been made by the running scenario.

Comment: thats pretty much what I needed. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Truncation removes the data leaving the database structure, transaction majorly rollback the database operation and it is the fastest strategy. And there is the last one which is deletion. Deletion deletes the data and removes the structure of the database, it is the slowest but safest.
You can also check [Difference between truncation, transaction and deletion database strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10904996/difference-between-truncation-transaction-and-deletion-database-strategies)